# Finding the minimum set of properties that describe a referent in a set of entities

Tags: algorithm, set

I was wondering if someone could help me get pointers to solve this problem. A link to algorithms would be great, but pointers to papers/info is also good.

The problem is as follows. Suppose I have a set E of entities `E={car1, car2, bicycle}` and a set of properties `P ={red, blue, small}`. I also have a knowledge base such that `red(bicycle), blue(car1), blue(car2), small(car2)`. Suppose I also have a referent `r` which belongs to `E`.

The problem consists of finding the minimum set of properties `P' \subseteq P` such that it unequivocally picks out `r` from `E`. Thus, if `r` is `car2`, then `P'={small}`.

Any ideas? I guess something like the set covering problem or functional dependencies (as in DB theory) might provide some insight, but I thought I'd ask before going into that literature. Yet another possibility is building graphs and find algorithms for subgraph isomorphisms... maybe.

Thanks.

Comment: What is `P'` for `bicycle`?  I have two variants: `{blue}` or `{red}`.  If we see something `red`, we unambiguously determine it's a `bicycle`.  But it's also apparent that if we see something `not blue`, then we can also reason it's a `bicycle`.  Is it the case?

Comment: Yes, Pavel. That is correct (frame problem, much?) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the set of all properties that r has. Call it S. For each property p in S, find e(p), all the entities that have the property p. It is clear for each p in S that e(p) contains r. Now take the intersections of e(p) for each p in S. If the intersection contains more than one entity, there is no solution, and we end the algorithm.

So we have a set S of properties that uniquely determine the entity r. Now we need to find a minimal subset of S that uniquely determines r. We can remove any property p from S for which there exists a property q in S so that e(p) is a superset of e(q). If you do that exhaustively you will eventually end up with a reduced set of properties T so that the intersection of e(p) for all the p in T will still be {r}, but no further property in T can be removed. This set T is then minimal.

I haven't thought of anything to make finding a property you can remove any more efficient than just trying all combinations, but it seems to me that there should be some way.

Comment: Hi, Joren. Yes, this was, details aside, my first attempt. As you say, however, it seems there must be a more efficient way to do this. That is what I am after. Thanks, upvoted! :)

Comment: The only improvement I've thought of is that you can precalculate/cache the results of subset-comparisons between properties, if you're going to run the algorithm several times for each property-entity system in stead of just once. It's not a massive improvement, and a pretty obvious one, so I suppose you had thought of it.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [minimum set cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem) of the set E\{r} with negations (complements) of those properties that r belongs to (properties can be treated as subsets of E).

Since these sets can be any sets, this is NP-hard.

More precisely:

Having a set cover instance (`U`,`S`) where `U` is the set that you need to cover and `S`={`s1`,`s2`, ..., `sn`}  is the family of covering sets you can construct an instance of your problem so that its solution gives a set cover in the original problem:

`E` = `U` \union {`r`}, where `r` is the referent and `r` does not belong to `U`.
The set of properties `P`={`p1`,`p2`, ..., `pn`} is constructed from `S` so that for each `e` in `U` and each `i` such that 1<=`i`<=n we have `pi`(`e`) iff `e` is not in `si`. Moreover each property is true for `r`. In other words properties are complements of the original sets when restricted to `U`, and `r` has all properties.

Now it is clear that each set of properties that selects `r` is a set cover in the original problem - if `r` is selected by a set `S*` of properties, then all other elements (that means all those in `U`) fail at least one property in `S*`, so every element of `U` belongs to at least one original set (from construction of properties as complements of the sets). That means that `U` is union of those sets from which properties in `S*` were constructed.

The converse is also true - a set cover in `U` translates to an `r`-selecting set in `E`.

The above reduction is obviously polynomial, so the problem is NP-hard.